# Adding a href in a control

Tags: asp.net

I have the checkbox seen below,and I want to do something like this

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="Accept" runat="server">
<a href="Terms.aspx">Accept terms</a>
```

But I want the  to be part of the asp CheckBox, so that I can do something like this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="AcceptCheckBox" runat="server" Text="Accept" <a href="'Agreement.aspx'">terms</a> first" />
```

Is that possible, and if so, how do you express it?

Comment: What you want to achieve by this ?. by click on `a` tag page will redirect, what the idea of using `checkbox` here

Comment: Having links in the text of the checkbox is not user friendly because clicking on the checkbox text one expects the checkbox to change state (not to open links).

Answer (score 3):

### Using label

You can use the `label` tag as:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="AcceptCheckBox" Text="" />
<label for="<%=AcceptCheckBox.ClientID %>">
    <a target="_blank" href="terms.html">terms</a> first
</label>
```

This is the test output: http://jsfiddle.net/5SVDk/1/

---

### Using asp:Label control

From the idea of @richard-deeming we can also use an asp:Label control to avoid the write on page, and the code will be:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="AcceptCheckBox" Text="" />
<asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="AcceptCheckBox">
    <a target="_blank" href="terms.html">terms</a> first
</asp:Label>
```

---

### Using the asp:CheckBox only

You can also use the code behind to add the link as:

```
AcceptCheckBox.Text = "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"terms.html\">terms</a> first";
```

and simple

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="AcceptCheckBox" />
```

<sub>all tested and they render the same html</sub>

Comment: You can avoid the `"<%= AcceptCheckBox.ClientID %>"` by using `<asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="AcceptCheckBox">`.

Comment: @RichardDeeming Nice idea ! I have add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" Text="go to <a href='http://www.yahoo.com'>yahoo</a>" runat="Server" />
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="Accept" Text='<a href="Terms.aspx">Accept terms</a>' runat="server" />
```

Comment: Are you sure this will work ?? as far my knwoledge checkbox  control will not work

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I have this:
<asp:CheckBox ID="AcceptCheckBox" Text="<a href="Terms.aspx">Accept terms first</a>" runat="server" />

I'm getting the following error (on the href):
Validation (ASP.NET) This attribute name mubst be followed by an equal(=) sign and value. If the value is in quotation marks, the quotation marks must match.

Comment: It gives warning `Validation (ASP.Net): Element 'CheckBox' is missing the '>' character from its start tag. `  and dispaly output as text `Accept terms" runat="server" /> `  no A tag no CheckBox

Comment: I made it work by:
<asp:CheckBox ID="AcceptCheckBox" Text='<a href="Terms.aspx"> Accept terms</a>' runat="server" />


So I had to use the ' instead of ". But your solution looks prettier Aristos, so I'll try that. Thanks to all for attempting to help